# matlab return every second occurrence of value in vector

Tags: matlab, vector, boolean, vectorization

I have a vector with ID numbers that repeat an even number of times. I am only interested in every second time each number appears. I want to create a boolean mask that gives a true/1 for each second occurance of a number. I have already done this with a loop, but the actual vector will contain millions of elements, so the loop is too slow. I need a "vectorized" solution.

Here is an example Vector:

```
101
102
103
101
104
102
101
103
101
104
```

This should output the following mask:

```
0 (first occurrence of 101)
0 (first occurrence of 102)
0 (first occurrence of 103)
1 (second occurrence of 101)
0 (first occurrence of 104)
1 (second occurrence of 102)
0 (third occurrence of 101) 
1 (second occurrence of 103)
1 (fourth occurrence of 101)
1 (second occurrence of 104)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) it for a vectorized solution -

```
%// Assuming A as the input vector
M = bsxfun(@eq,A(:),unique(A(:).'))  %//'
out = any(M - mod(cumsum(M,1).*M,2),2)
```

Comment: @rayryeng Well `M` is the mask of all unique occurances. `mod(cumsum(M,1).*M,2)` is the occurance of all odd occurances, so subtracting it from `M` gives us the even occurances and finally `any` as the final output is to be a vector. Hope that makes sense! And how was this  for `golfing` ;)

Comment: Excellent, and the most "elegant" and completely vectorized solution. I'm going to have to change my accepted answer. Both you and rayryeng have 40k+ rating, so I don't think it will impact you too much. Thank you to rayryeng, excaza, and Divakar for helping. All the answers were excellent. I didn't think I'd have three solutions to pick from, especially not so quickly!

Comment: @Trashman - I'd choose this answer as well.  Divakar has a way with vectorization.  Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this very easily with a combination of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  First assign each value a unique ID, then bin all array locations together that are part of the same ID.  You'll need to sort them as `accumarray` doesn't guarantee an order when you are binning things together.  The output of this will be a cell array where each cell gives you the array locations that occurred for a particular index.

Once you do this, extract out every second element from each cell generated from `accumarray`, then use these to set all of the corresponding locations in a mask to 1.  You can use a combination of [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), which can be used to process each cell individually and extracting every second element to create a new cell array, and [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) which can be used to stack all of the cell arrays together into one final index array.  This index array can be used to accomplish setting the locations in your mask to `true`:

```
%// Your data
V = [101,102,103,101,104,102,101,103,101,104];

%// Get list of unique IDs
[~,~,id] = unique(V,'stable');

%// Bin all of the locations in V together that belong to the
%// same bin
out = accumarray(id, (1:numel(V)).',[], @(x) {sort(x)}); %'

%// Extract out every second value that is for each bin
out2 = cellfun(@(x) x(2:2:end), out, 'uni', 0);

%// Create a mask and set the corresponding locations to true
mask = false(numel(V), 1);
mask(vertcat(out2{:})) = 1;
```

We get:

```
>> mask

mask =

     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     1
     1
     1
```

Comment: I got stuck at the `unique` part once I realised it just changed my variable numbers and I still needed a loop. Good work using my best friend `accumarray`

Comment: This is working on my example vector. On my real vector, however, on `mask(cell2mat(out2)) = 1;` I get: `Error using cat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. Error in cell2mat (line 83) m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});` What could be causing this? Is it that some values appear an odd number of times?

Comment: @Trashman - That shouldn't matter.  Let me modify it so it doesn't use `cell2mat`... that's probably where the error is coming from.

Comment: @Trashman - I've replaced `cell2mat` with `vertcat`. I've also ensured that all of the indices for each bin are column vectors.  Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: Yes, vertcat works! FYI: I did track down the cell2mat problem a little farther. Some of my elements in out2 were empty. If I chose a range that stopped before the first empty cell, it didn't give the error, if I included the empty cell it gave an error. I suspect the empty may have been due to a particular ID only occurring once in the original value. I'm not going to track it down any further since vertcat works, though. Thank you!

Comment: @Trashman - Cool!  I got rid of the column vector formatting as `vertcat` works.  Thanks for the accept :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach:

```
A = [101,102,103,101,104,102,101,103,101,104];
IDs = unique(A); % Find all the IDs present

test = arrayfun(@(x) find(A==x), IDs, 'UniformOutput', false); % Per ID, find where A == ID
repeatidx = cellfun(@(x) x(2:2:length(x)), test, 'UniformOutput', false); % Dump out the second match
repeatidx = cell2mat(repeatidx); % Flatten the cell array

B = false(size(A)); % Intialize output boolean array
B(repeatidx) = true; % Set true values based on repeatidx
```

Which returns:

```
B =

     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Similar to rayryeng's original response, 'cell2mat' gives me an error in my real data. I think it fails when an element doesn't actually repeat. 'Vertcat' works better. Exact Syntax: `repeatidx = vertcat(repeateidx{:})`. with that replacement, your method also works! Thank You.

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer, too. Unfortunately, I can only accept one. Rayryeng got it for being the first, but your answer is just as good (with one modification). I did give you an upvote. Thanks again.

Comment: @Trashman the problem with `vertcat` with this method is that it will not function if there are multiple double repeats of the value (e.g. 101 in your example, where our mask is `true` twice) since the nested array sizes will be different.

Comment: Vote from me as well. It turns out you posted first by a few seconds. Feel bad for taking your accept!

Comment: @excaza when I tried this method, replacing cell2mat with vertcat, using it on my actual data, and comparing it to the results I got from rayryeng's method, the masks checked as exactly identical to eachother. So, either yours doesn't have that problem using vertcat after all, or they both do... I don't think they do but I'll check my data closer.